# how to push Ruby on Rails site from Mac OS X to Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I'm on my MacBook Air developing with RoR and a SQLite database and when I'm happy with my site I want to push it to my Windows server (which is actually running Windows 7, but oh well), because I have MSSQL and lots of unused resources there.

I'm quite surprised I wasn't able to find much about this topic.  Has anyone accomplished that?  If yes, can you please write a quick description of the setup?

Some of what I tried:
1- I installed Ruby on Rails for Windows and tried to setup a separate RoR development environment for Windows.  Down side: the fact that the latest stable Ruby version for Windows is 1.93 and I'm using Ruby v2.1.1 on OS X.

2- I set up IIS following this [great walkthrough written by Durgaprasad Gorti](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2009/06/17/ruby-on-rails-with-iis-7-reloaded.aspx) that uses CGI for the rendering.  I'm not precisely sure what this does yet, but I'm a bit biased I admit.  It's definitely not the type of deployment solution I have in mind for RoR.

3- I'm looking at deploying Apache for Windows and see if it's easier to deploy a RoR website to it as I've just finished downloading Phusion Passenger.

My understanding so far is that there are a series of deployment tools available that make it easy to parameterize deployment on OS X and Linux, but none exists for Windows.

Comment: Passenger doesn't support windows

Answer (score 0):

> It's not the deploying of ROR that's the challenge here - it's
>   creating an environment which allows it to run. You can just use
>   [git](http://git-scm.com/) & [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/rails) to push / deploy your app. Rails apps are
>   just a series of files & dependencies which should run in any
>   environment, considering you have it set up correctly

I've set up linux boxes for production before, but not Windows. So the only recommendation I have is to say that if you want to get ROR deployed to a Windows environment -- you'll have to ensure you have all the dependencies required to make the app run. You've cited `2.1.1 etc`, the best advice I have is to make sure you have this & your other dependencies installed (using the likes of `ImageMagick` etc to use `Paperclip` etc)

If you get the dependencies set up, then you can set up a server to handle the inbound requests. After that, you should be able to run the app from your Windows box.... although I'd highly recommend using a flavour of Linux such as Ubuntu on a cloud hosting provider (we use [RackSpace](http://rackspace.com))

Comment: Yes of course! Heroku makes deployment very easy, and they still run Amazon's cloud hosting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/) to run Ruby on IIS.